# MediaPlayer, only video m3u8 HTML streams work

Tags: android, stream, streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm using the MediaPlayer with a m3u8 audio stream. This results in a log error message: `Error(1, -1010)`

The first argument seems ok when I look at the error codes: https://github.com/android/platform_external_opencore/blob/master/pvmi/pvmf/include/pvmf_return_codes.h

Only `-1010`, is strange.

When I use the apple video `m3u8` url it's working great! This is the url:
http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8

The code I'm using is simple:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8");
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.start();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) { 
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Does anyone know if there is a limitation for audio only streams? I used multiple formats and different extensions.

Other question: does anyone have an URL of an m3u8 audio stream, so I can test other streams?

Comment: Hi Ben, Is this  http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8 link is working for you.

Comment: Hi Vinaykumar, yes that one is working.

Comment: @BenGroot Is the audio stream a segmented MP3 or segmented ts? Can you use Apple's mediastreamvalidator tool to investigate it?

Comment: Thanks, the Apple mediastreamvalidator tool stated some errors. We are working on it now. I'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently attached to a project tackling this very subject.
Now I know this doesn't really answer your question, but just for insight, even on Android 4.0+ M3U8 support is spotty at best, awful at worst.

E.g.:

- Nexus 7 fails on Akmai, works on UStream
- Droid RAZR works on both Akmai and UStream.

Now short of patching the libraries via class extension (and having .so's for every other android minor version) we found no SDK/NDK-only solution; we gave up after a month of trial and error on our project (too costly).

The solution we implemented was: Try the SDK MediaPlayer. If that fails use a FFMPEG based player (developed in-house, using dranger, ffplay, android-fplayer and dolphin-player as inspiration).